# Socket recv() one byte at a time

Tags: c++, performance, sockets, tcp, recv

Is it a good idea to call `recv()` one byte at a time with sockets (in terms of performance)? Does it cause a context switch? If so why is there a context switch?

Comment: I am just lazy... Calling recv() one byte at a time would just make it easier for me to parse the incoming request

Comment: I'm not really sure about the terminology but I created the socket with that line `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`

Comment: So a connected, TCP, IPv4 socket.

Comment: "_I am just lazy..._" OK, then why aren't you using iostream or C stdio?

Comment: Note that you can recv() into a larger buffer and then still parse the received bytes one at a time if you want to; just put a for-loop after the recv() call that iterates over the valid bytes that recv() wrote to.

Comment: Also how do I go about configuring the socket for use with IPv6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `recv()` one byte at a time will negatively impact performance. There is a certain amount of overhead on each call -- the transition to kernel mode, file descriptor lookup, dispatch to the protocol-specific driver, buffer/queue locking, etc. Calling `recv()` with larger buffers greatly decreases the average overhead per byte.

Comment: Thanks! What is the usual size for the buffer used in this case? Also is there a max set on the number of bytes that can be sent using the send() function?

Comment: @Aaryaman People usually use several kilobytes, e.g. 8192, for receive buffers. The only limit on the amount you can send per call is the range of the length parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's absolutely not a good idea.

Calling the read function has a lot of overhead compared to just reading and writing
one byte in RAM, you don't want to do the whole work for every byte.